# Mysterious "unabled nested data-type expression" in Z3

Tags: constraints, z3

I changed an `assert` to an `assert-soft` and now I get an error "unabled nested data-type expression". What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a typo in the code. The optimization mode believes it can translate your data-type expressions into enumeration types, but encounters an expression it does not know to handle. The code needs to be fixed to check for this condition. 
A small repro would be useful. I can fix the typo in the exception message, but it will not address the bug. If you can file an issue on https://github.com/z3prover with repro it will be appreciated.

Comment: I saw you already fixed the typo Nikolaj (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/996c0f0666f18ad4719135aa3e964fb6c9103c35). I will try to make the program smaller and create an issue.